# Infinite Sets Proof - Integer Sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, integers

Let $Z^- $ be the set of negative numbers. Prove $Z^-$ ≈ $Z^+$ by finding a bijective function $f : Z^+-> Z^+$. Prove that the function is bijective.

Could someone tell me how to get started on this? I know there exist a point where $Z^+$ and $Z^-$ are bijective, but I don't know how to find a function that would do so. Any help is greatly appreciated!

The "≈" symbol is another way of saying bijection in this case.

Comment: How about $z \mapsto -z$?

Comment: So $Z^-$ contains numbers such as $-1,-17,-42,-66$ whereas $Z^+$ contains numbers such as $1,17,42,666$. I guess a bijection really suggests itself immediately ,,,

Comment: How do you know a bijection exists if you can't find one?

Comment: I assume that should be a bijective function $f:\mathbb{Z}^+\to\mathbb{Z}^-$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are having more conceptual difficulties. The problem is fairly straightforward in this case, the solution (as mentioned by others) is quite easy to come up with.

I just wanted to outline how one might approach this problem, since you did not know how to do just that.

First we are asked to find a bijection between the sets $\{1,2,3,...\}$ and $\{-1,-2,-3,...\}$. Recall exactly what a bijective functions is:

> A function $f:A\to B$ is *bijective* if and only if it is both injective (one to one) and surjective (onto).

Essentially this means that for every point $a$ in the $A$, domain of $f$, there exists a unique and distinct point that $a$ maps to, and for every element $b$ in $B$, there exists an element in $A$ that maps to $b$.

An analogy is that the bijection creates a very nice partnering of all the elements in $A$ with all the elements in $B$, where everyone in $A$ has their own unique partner in $B$ (no one in $A$ 'shares', that is, maps to the same partner in $B$), and no one in $B$ is left unpartnered.

So the goal of the exercise is to create such a partnership between the sets $\{1,2,3,...\}$ and $\{-1,-2,-3,...\}$ mathematically by defining a function. So to get on your way, start with an element in the first set, say $1$. Who shall we partner $1$ with in the second set? Now there are many ways you can do this, but we just want to make it easy, hence we will partner it with $-1$.

Now we continue: pick $2$, who should we partner it with? Probably $-2$. How about $3$? Partner that with $-3$. How about $4$? And $5$? And...?

Look at the pattern for our 'function':
$$1\mapsto -1$$
$$2\mapsto -2$$
$$3\mapsto -3$$
$$...$$
And we arrive at the conclusion that:
$$n\mapsto -n.$$

Now all you have to do is to prove that $f:n\mapsto -n$ is indeed bijective (according to the strict, rigorous mathematical definition, not my flimsy "partnership" one).

Comment: (And this "rigorous mathematical proof" should also be simple, just a quick check that both injectivity and surjectivity do hold.) +1 though. This is what OP needs, not just to be given the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try the function $n \mapsto -n$